# Display camera stream in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, camera, xamarin-community-toolkit

I want to display the stream of a camera inside a page. Like that:

[image: Camera view in my application]

Mainly, the application runs on Windows 10. I have set Fall Creators Update (16299) as minimal version of Windows.

I have found CameraView (from Xamarin Community Toolkit - 1.2.0) but it doesn't work... Explanations:

I use states (from the toolkit):

- "Loading" to display an ActivityIndicator,
- "None" to display the camera stream and other controls,
- "Success" to display the taked image,
- "Error" to display an error.

I use the basic MVVM pattern, generated by Visual Studio template. My page is attached to ViewModel in XAML:

```
<ContentPage ...>
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:FooViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid ...>
        <xct:StateLayout.StateViews>

            <xct:StateView StateKey="Loading">
                <ActivityIndicator .../>
            </xct:StateView>

            <xct:StateView StateKey="None" 
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <xct:CameraView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                CaptureMode="Photo"
                                CameraOptions="Default"/>
            </xct:StateView>
        </xct:StateLayout.StateViews>

        <CollectionView Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I have try to move the CameraView control outside of the StateLayout. The control is displayed in "Live Visual Tree" but the camera doesn't display a stream.

### On UWP:

I have check that "Camera" and "Microphone" capabilities are enabled.

When "None" state is setted (after "Loading" state), my controls are visible on "Live Visual Tree" except the CameraView...
[image]

### On Android

I have check that "RecordAudio" and "Camera" permissions are enabled on Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I use the Android Emulator.

Same behavior... But! When I move the CameraView to the Grid, the camera streams and it displayed!

### Other information

- My webcam works (in Windows Camera app)
- I use Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0 to request permissions
- I have try with VS2019 and VS2021 with .NET 5

### Update 06/09/2021

I removed state management. I also tried using the Visual State Manager (provided in the Xamarin.Forms APIs) :

```
<Grid...>
<xct:CameraView
    x:Name="cameraView"
    CaptureMode="Photo"
    FlashMode="Off"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    MediaCaptured="MediaCaptured"
    OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="FooStates">
        <VisualState Name="State0">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="State1">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="State2">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</xct:CameraView>
</Grid>
```

And finally, remote entirely the state management:

```
<Grid....>
<xct:CameraView
    x:Name="cameraView"
    CaptureMode="Photo"
    FlashMode="Off"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    MediaCaptured="RecognitionCameraView_MediaCaptured"
    OnAvailable="RecognitionCameraView_OnAvailable"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    IsVisible="{Binding CameraIsVisible}"/>
</Grid>
```

The result is the same... The page doesn't display the camera stream on Windows...

### Xamarin Community Toolkit Sample

I tried the Xamarin Community Tollkit sample application, the CameraView works.
I even tried copying the XAML from the sample... The page doesn't display the camera stream on Windows...

### Workaround

Finally, I failed to stream the camera on Windows with the `CameraView` control (from `Xamarin.Community.Toolkit` package)...

I opted for a basic alternative solution: the **Custom Renderers**.

I was inspired by Xamarin official documentation and his sample. The code is available here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view and
- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/View

Comment: Did you try to move `CameraView`  to the Grid in uwp ? It seems that the problem is related to the `xct:StateLayout.StateViews` not cameraView .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT : Done. I am updating the question.