# CameraView of Xamarin.CommunityToolkit not available in UWP-App Release Mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.communitytoolkit

I'm using the CameraView in my Multiplattform-application. It works fine under iOS, and Android. In my UWP-Application the cameraView works if i start the app in debug-mode and I can see the camera-stream. But in Release-mode the property is available is false and i do not see the stream.
Im using the newest Version of CommunityToolkit (2.0.6).
Minimum TargetVersion is Win 10, version 1903

Comment: Did it throw any error? There are some issues you may refer to: [Camera not open in UWP in my xamarin.forms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010806/camera-not-open-in-uwp-in-my-xamarin-forms-app), [Display camera stream in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043093/display-camera-stream-in-xamarin), [CameraView not showing/working on UWP](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/758)

Comment: No, there is no Error. I've used the camera-functionality of xam.plugin.media before and this works always. but i have to change to community toolkit for some reasons.

Comment: What issue are you facing on Release mode exactly?

Comment: the CameraView does not show the preview in release mode. It is not NULL but the property "available" is false.

Comment: You may try [customizing a cameraview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) as an alternative or you could raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues).